# Suitable replacement for java to develop a cross-platform application

Tags: java, performance, qt, cross-platform

I've always used java for developing cross platform applications, however, this time java can not solve my problem. The problem is, I have to develop an application which is computationally expensive. More precisely, in my application there is a simulation which is a little too heavy. I made a java prototype app but it's not fast enough and I have some lag in my simulation so I started to think to switch to c++.
My application has a GUI and I was wondering if I want to switch to c++ for a cross platform application, what should I do with GUI?
My questions are:

1. If I use Qt framework, is my application going to be *significantly* faster?
2. If I deploy my jar file to native os executable (.exe, .app, etc) is my application going to be *significantly* faster?

p.s. Mac OSx, Windows and Ubuntu are target platforms for my software.

Comment: Have you analyzed where the performance is slow in the Java version and tried to improve that?

Comment: Yes. I cleaned/improved my code up-to the highest level possible. Still slow. Threading also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: As @JonSkeet said, once you find the problems in the Java version and improved it you could always write the "slow" parts in C++ and invoke via JNI

Comment: What sort of computation are you doing? Depending on what you are doing, the limitation could be in the choice of hardware you are using.  IMHO, there are few problems which are dramatically faster in C++ than Java, you might see improvements of 10-30% but you can also get this improvement by using faster hardware.

Comment: @Pouya: a *.app* is just a directory.  Java apps shipped as *.app* on OS X just contain the *.jar* inside the *.app* so it changes nothing.

Comment: @Pouya: I wasn't talking just about "cleaning and improving" - I was talking about profiling and analyzing your code to find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Two inner loops, each 500 iterations (total 500 power 2), inside the inner loop, I have to do several mathematical calculations (all double precisions). This is the bottle neck. In such calculation, is c++ going to be any better?

Answer (score 4):

This Article may Help You, I Face the same questions a couple of years ago. I decided to stick with Java for my own programming experience, since I'm not that good in C++ and my project was to be honest, very simple. As you know, Java is a very spread / wide around the world, tons of docs and libraries ready for you to use, Qt is faster, but you will need to get your hands dirty to do the job. If performance is your goal, Go Qt. Or redesign your application to hava Java/Swing GUI and C++ programs server side. Anyways here's the link.

http://turing.iimas.unam.mx/~elena/PDI-Lic/qt-vs-java-whitepaper.pdf

Java/Swing may be appropriate for certain projects, especially those without GUIs 
or with limited GUI functionality. C++/Qt is an overall superior solution, particularly for GUI applications.

Comment: +1 for Qt! It is definitely the way to go for portable GUI apps in C++ if you don't want/cannot do Java.

Answer (score 2):

Using C++ instead of Java improves CPU performance, sometimes as much as 10-30%.  However using multiple threads also increases the amount of CPU you have available.  Given using multiple threads didn't help, I suspect your bottleneck is not in CPU and switching language is unlikely to help.

Where C can help is in programming graphics cards, e.g. CUDA.  You can get dramatically faster results for certain types of problems using a high performance processing card. http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/cuda_home_new_uk.html There are JOCL libraries to use CUDA from Java, but the code which does the real work is in a C-like language.

I suggest you determine where your bottle neck really is as switching to C++ will not increase the size of your cache, your memory bandwidth, IO bandwidth or the size of your main memory.